# I have symfony version 1.4 . I wanted to know is it possible to upgrade from 1.4 to 3

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, symfony-1.4

I have symfony version 1.4 . I wanted to know is it possible to upgrade from 1.4 to 3. if yes then how we can do it ?

Comment: You can use Composer to upgrade any package.

Comment: can you please let me the command i need to run in terminal 
i have used the command composer update

Comment: What are you working on ? Firstly, create a composer.json file which will help composer download your dependencies. Please Google abit :-)

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: **NO**

`Symfony 1.x` is from pre-composer era so you can't use composer to upgrade. In fact there is no direct path to upgrade from `Symfony` 1.x to 2.x (3.x). `Symfony` 1.x and 2.x are completly different, it's safe to say that only thing they have in common is name.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that there is [a fork of Symfony 1 available for composer](https://github.com/LExpress/symfony1) though. That being said, the rest of your answer is absolutely correct, version 1 and 2 have nothing in common, they are basically 2 different frameworks.

Comment: In most cases it makes zero business sense to port an application, however it's possible to run Symfony 1.4 and 2.0 together using a [wrapper library](https://github.com/Ingewikkeld/IngewikkeldWrapperBundle)

Answer (score 0):

**Since 2017**, to upgrade from **Symfony 2.8 to 3.4** (at the moment), you might find useful this tool:

- [RectorPHP](https://github.com/RectorPHP/Rector)

It is AST-based automated refactoring tool, to use in CLI.

At the time of writing this it contains around ~60 changes. Still growing every day.